# How can we get different mean and median values for residuals when working with the same dataset?

Tags: r, regression, residuals

Following this R instruction

```
> fit <- lm(spending ~ sex + status + income + verbal, data=spending)
```

I would like to calculate the mean and median of the residuals. Both my friend and I get different answers for the mean for the same data.

```
> mean(resid(fit))
[1] -3.065293e-17
```

while with the other model, results are:

```
> fit1<- lm(spending ~ status + income + sex + verbal, data=spending) 
> mean(resid(fit1))
[1] 4.064605e-16
```

Why did we get the same median but different mean if we are using the same data set?

Comment: The mean of the residuals should be zero. Small deviations from zero may be due to rounding issues. Note that your obtained values are indeed very small.

Comment: It's an intriguing question.  (If "rounding issues" affect your friend, they ought to affect you the same way.) What have you done to rule out simple explanations, such as *any* difference between your data set and your friend's? A single typographical error in one of them would explain this difference.

Comment: "Small" compared to what, @Sven?  See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37522 for an account of the issues.  (You and I know that mean residuals for a linear model with intercept should be exactly zero, but nevertheless an order of magnitude difference between two computations could flag something serious going on and is worth looking into: I applaud the questioner for paying attention to this.)

Comment: Sven's point is good. When the computer rounds at very low values, it causes these sorts of problems. Effectively both answers are 0 though. Reminds of me this blog post: http://davegiles.blogspot.com/2011/12/reported-accuracy-for-regression.html

Comment: That begs the point, @John: when two computers are ostensibly doing exactly the same computations with exactly the same data, then they should be making *exactly* the same floating point errors. These little things are often the only clues one gets that something more significant is wrong; they shouldn't be dismissed just because the values are "very low." (Do you remember the [Pentium bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug)?) In fact, in the scheme of things--doubles range from about $10^{-303}$ to $10^{303}$--values around $10^{-17}$ aren't small at all; they are middling values.

Comment: @whuber it isn't clear to me that they *are* doing the same thing. The ordering of the variables in the model formulae shown is different in the two fits.

Comment: @Gavin: Exactly! That's what I'm getting at. The point is that *something* is different and the first places to look are in the data and the code. (I suspect that a simple check of this nature will enable this question to resolve itself.)

Comment: However, as far as R is concerned the means of the two sets of residuals **are** indistinguishable given machine precision. Try `all.equal(-3.065293e-17, 4.064605e-16)`.

Comment: @Gavin Try `4.064605e-16 / -3.065923e-17`!  (More important point: just because `all.equal` uses a default tolerance of `.Machine$double.eps^0.5`, which is around $10^{-8}$, does not mean it is appropriate for this comparison. It's not. The appropriate tolerance depends on the typical sizes of the residuals themselves, which we do not know in this case.)

Comment: Please, [register](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#login) your account. That will enhance your experience with this site and will allow you to vote on and accept previous answers.

Comment: Maybe the order of variables affects the order in which computations are made and hence affects what the roundoff error will be.  I guess these days computers have the same high precision.  But in the old days the machines could have different numbers of bits for storing numbers and so two machines could differ like this just because the precision of the floating point arithmetic is different.

Comment: @whuber, technically speaking they aren't doing the same calculation. The ordering when computing the inverse is what really matters, I think.

Comment: Yes, I agree @John: that's the likeliest explanation--but not the only possible one.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, the mean of the residuals of both models should be zero. Deviations are due to rounding issues.

Here's an example:

```
> x <- rnorm(10)
> y <- rnorm(10)
> z <- rnorm(10)
> res1 <- residuals(lm(y ~ x+z))
> res2 <- residuals(lm(y ~ z+x))
```

Note that both models include the same variables, but the order is different.

Look at the mean:

```
> mean(res1)
[1] 3.8849e-17
> mean(res2)
[1] 1.525337e-17
> median(res1)
[1] 0.06405684
> median(res2)
[1] 0.06405684
```

The mean is not identical, but the median is.

The residuals are nearly identical (as expected):

```
> all.equal(sort(res1), sort(res2))
 [1] TRUE
```

Check `?all.equal`.

But they are not completely identical:

```
> identical(as.numeric(sort(res1)), as.numeric(sort(res2)))
[1] FALSE
```

The deviance from zero is due to rounding issues in `R`. Hence, the difference in the order of model predictors may cause this kind of differences.

Comment: @whuber...we are using the data from the R library and used a lm as I stated above. Could it have to do with the way we created the lm. I mean the order of predictors in our lm differ but we both used all the predictors?

Comment: Yes, the difference in mean residuals is due to the order of predictors. Mathematically, both models should have mean residuals of excatly 0.

Comment: thank you, my friend and I were both checking if we may have omitted something in each of our linear model when we got different results. This was helpful

Comment: @Gavin@whuber so technically if 5 people using the same dataset from R and the order of the variables being used are different in the lm, then each person will have different means. (Even though the data is the same)